# Open several files in separate tabs in vim using command prompt

Tags: vim

I was expecting that command:

```
vim hello.c hello.h
```

should open both files in separate tabs. Unfortunately this opens just `hello.c`. How to open both?

Comment: You have to use `-p`. Like `vim -p hello.c hello.h`. The way you are doing it does _not_ open only `hello.c` -- it uses buffers instead of tabs.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist This should be the answer, not the comment.

Comment: @Paul Yes, sorry. Internet was being flaky and I couldn't post.

Comment: Why do you expect that? And how do you know only one file is opened?

Comment: And related: why in separate *tabs* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vim -p hello.c hello.h`

From `vim -h`:

```
-p[N]                Open N tab pages (default: one for each file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open files in split panes from the cli using `vim -o`  for horizontal split or `vim -O` for vertical split. Or, once you already have vim open (after using the command from your question) you can open additional buffers into split panes using `:sb 2` (or some other buffer number) for horizontal panes or `:vert sb 2` for vertical split.

Comment: The question asks about tabs not splits.

Comment: I was operating under the assumption that someone whose question suggests they aren't even familiar with buffers might not necessarily understand the proper terminology for various ways to open multiple files in vim. But I guess it is your right to downvote based on your very literal interpretation of the question. Cheers.

Comment: You chose with no explanation to completely ignore the question. If you wanted to answer it and then proceed with all this explanation you would have gotten an upvote.